# USB/External Hard drives not recognised on Windows10 machine after being mounted on Ubuntu machine

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

Newbie from non-tech background.
I have been copying and pasting from an Ubuntu machine to External Hard drives/USB keys then trying to access data on windows 10 machine.  This had been working for awhile.  Now windows 10 wont recognize the drives or keys.
"E:\ is not accessible.  The volume does not contain a recognized file system" 
Properties shows show disk as 0 bytes used space and 0 bytes free space.
Any advice on fixing disks? and how to safely move files between machines?
Thanks

Comment: Have you formeted the drives in Ubuntu? If so, with what file system? Windows  recognizes FAT and NTFS only.

Comment: Which program are you using to create the disk?  Also, multiplesession records and unclosed sessions looses compatibility between computers.  Have you tested making sure it's one session and the disk is closed after the recording?

Comment: @L. D. James - The issue with multiple sessions is applicable to optical media, not USB flash drives.

Comment: I haven't formatted the disk drives.  Don't want to lose the data stored on them.  They had been working between the two machines fine as they were.  I have had some problems with the ubuntu machine not looking like it had unmounted the usb properly.  (USB would disappear off side bar but no message to confirm it had been dismounted.)

Comment: @CelticWarrior sudo fdisk -l shows:  /dev/sdb1 System HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Answer (score 0):

You could try copying the files off the external hard disk into the Ubuntu filesystem and then use `sudo cfdisk` in the terminal  to format the external hard disk to either FAT or NTFS before copying the files back to the external hard disk.

Just make sure to use FAT (or FAT32) or NTFS as these are the only formats Windows supports.

Cfdisk is pretty self-explanatory but if you need help there is plenty of help on the internet - just google.

Comment: If you need to ask use comments. An answer should be formated as such.

Comment: I couldn't comment - I don't have 50 reputation yet.

Comment: Then please answer the questions you know already and don't need additional clarification.